# Reverse-Engineering an Application without EULA

Tags: software, eula

The place where I work have recently installed a tool on our computer systems. However there are a few things that I don't quite like about the tool and would like to improve them. However I am wondering if this possible?

I'd like to point out a couple of important things:

- The software came pre-installed. I didn't install it and never agreed to any EULA
- I have made reasonable effort to find the EULA - by downloading the setup system and also checking the site, however I could not find the EULA anywhere.

Does this mean that I can reverse-engineer the application to fit my needs better? I don't plan on making any commercial benefit from this or re-distribute it as my own. However I do plan on passing the fixed code to the others at work if it will also serve of help to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not without permission**

The creator of the program has copyright in it: you are proposing to make a derivative work and for this you need permission.

Comment: Thank you for that. It appears that the system has been abandoned and no longer actively maintained as of late. I have tried to contact the developers but have not received any feedback as of yet. Is there any clause (such as educational purposes) which would allow me to de-compile and fix the code as "fair use".

In addition - though this might come across as cheeky - would adding a disclaimer stating that this was done for x purposes and should be immediately deleted, free me from the burden of liability? I'm just checking the options at this point rather than trying to infringe copyright.

Comment: No and no. Someone, somewhere owns the copyright - it's quite likely they either don't know or don't care that they do but they can exercise their rights at any time